# Potential .NET x86 JIT issue?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, jit

The following code behaves differently when built in Release mode (or Debug with optimizations on) and run **without** the Visual Studio debugger attached.

It also only seems to replicate if the x86 JITter is used. I have tested this on an x86 machine as well as running in WOW64 on a x64 machine (by setting the Platform target to x86).

I've only tried this with .NET 4.0.

When running outside the debugger in Release I see:

```
Value is 4
```

When running inside the debugger the `e.Value.Length` portion of the `WriteLine` call throws `NullReferenceException`, which is what I expected to have happen.

The code:

```
namespace Test
{
    class UsingReleasable<T>
    {
        public UsingReleasable(T obj)
        {
            m_obj = obj;
        }

        public T Release()
        {
            T tmp = m_obj;
            m_obj = default(T);
            return tmp;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get { return m_obj; }
        }

        T m_obj;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var e = new UsingReleasable<string>("test");
            e.Release();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}", e.Value.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

My peering at the JIT generated code makes me think it is a bug in that piece, but I wanted to double check here before forwarding this on to MS Connect.

Comment: Can you post the jit as well?

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again: "If you think you've found a problem with the .NET runtime (`Potential .NET x86 JIT issue?`) you're probably wrong". Now let me look at this again.

Comment: @jcole that the code behaves differently depending on jit optimizations being enabled is a strong sign that it is indeed a jitter bug. Especially since this code contains no unsafe code.

Comment: I would vote for this to be a bug. Just tried it and it does indeed  behave differently in release and debug

Comment: Wouldn't be the first JITter bug found on StackOverflow, although usually the x64 JITter is the buggy one :) SELECT may not be broken often, but the JITter sometimes is.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I know, it was just something I always say in this case of complaint. Nothing against the OP (hence my desire to look into it further ;) )

Comment: If you change it from using 'var' to use a static type -- UsingReleasable<string> for example -- does this change the behavior?

Comment: @Dan `var` ***is*** static typed (just implicit, not explicit) - and in this case it *is* `UsingReleasable<string>` ;p But indeed, with an odd bug like this little can be assumed...

Comment: @jcolebrand I agree with the statement about "If you think..." in my experience the same is true with bugs in the compiler, the OS, the BCL, etc. I ran this by the smart folks I work with and we thought it was time to push it to the cognoscenti here.

Comment: @FatKenny And you did well my friend ;) ~ And welcome to [SO] for what it's worth, where have you been?

Comment: Looks odd to me... will ping Eric Lippert.

Comment: @Marc - you just made something 'click' for me.  ;-)  I just got schooled.

Comment: @jcolebrand - Lurking I guess :)

Comment: @FatKenny - +1 for teaching me the word 'cognoscenti'.  That's a $50 word if I ever heard one.

Comment: @Jon: No point, the C# compiler is doing the right thing (`initobj` is a valid way to clear `e.Value`).

Comment: I'm pleased to report that the status of [the Connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679116/x86-jit-improperly-reorders-load-of-field-of-generic-type-with-assignment-to-default-t#details) has been changed to fixed, although when we outside Microsoft see the fix is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 21):

I can reproduce your behavior:

> ```
> R:\>csc /platform:x86 releasable.cs
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
>
> R:\>releasable
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
> an instance of an object.
>    at Test.Program.Main(String[] args)
>
> R:\>csc /o+ /platform:x86 releasable.cs
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
>
> R:\>releasable
> Value is 4
>
> R:\>csc /platform:anycpu releasable.cs
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
>
> R:\>releasable
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
> an instance of an object.
>    at Test.Program.Main(String[] args)
>
> R:\>csc /o+ /platform:anycpu releasable.cs
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
>
> R:\>releasable
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
> an instance of an object.
>    at Test.Program.Main(String[] args)
> ```

The `/checked` compiler option makes no difference.  Neither does generation of debug data `/debug+`.  And the problem persists when `Console.ReadLine()` is called (to give a chance to attach the debugger and see optimized code.

---

I made a slight modification to `Main` to permit debugging of the optimized code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var e = new UsingReleasable<string>("test");
        System.Console.WriteLine("attach now");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
        e.Release();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}", e.Value.Length);
    }
```

And the actual disassembly:

```
--- r:\releasable.cs -----------------------------------------------------------
            var e = new UsingReleasable<string>("test");
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        edi 
00000004  push        esi 
00000005  mov         ecx,1839B0h 
0000000a  call        FFF81FB0 
0000000f  mov         esi,eax 
00000011  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[03772030h] 
00000017  lea         edx,[esi+4] 
0000001a  call        60452F70 
            System.Console.WriteLine("attach now");
0000001f  call        5E927060 
00000024  mov         ecx,eax 
00000026  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[03772034h] 
0000002c  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx] 
0000002e  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+3Ch] 
00000031  call        dword ptr [eax+10h] 
00000034  call        5EEF9A40 
00000039  mov         ecx,eax 
0000003b  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx] 
0000003d  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+2Ch] 
00000040  call        dword ptr [eax+1Ch] 
            e.Release();
00000043  mov         edi,dword ptr [esi+4]              ; edi = e.Value
00000046  lea         esi,[esi+4]                        ; esi = &e.Value
00000049  xor         edx,edx                            ; edx = null
0000004b  mov         dword ptr [esi],edx                ; *esi = edx (e.Value = null)
0000004d  mov         ecx,5EBE28F8h
00000052  call        FFF81FB0
00000057  mov         edx,eax 
00000059  mov         eax,dword ptr [edi+4]              ; this sets EAX to 4
0000005c  mov         dword ptr [edx+4],eax 
0000005f  mov         esi,edx 
00000061  call        5E927060 
00000066  push        esi 
00000067  mov         ecx,eax 
00000069  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[03772038h] 
0000006f  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx] 
00000071  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+3Ch] 
00000074  call        dword ptr [eax+18h]                ; this results in the output "Value is 4\n"
00000077  pop         esi 
        }
00000078  pop         edi 
00000079  pop         ebp 
0000007a  ret
```

When the program starts under the debugger, this code is generated instead (and does produce a `NullReferenceException`:

```
--- r:\releasable.cs -----------------------------------------------------------
            var e = new UsingReleasable<string>("test");
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  sub         esp,24h 
00000006  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
00000009  cmp         dword ptr ds:[001E313Ch],0 
00000010  je          00000017 
00000012  call        606B6807 
00000017  xor         edx,edx 
00000019  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],edx 
0000001c  mov         ecx,1E39B0h 
00000021  call        FFF91FB0 
00000026  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax 
00000029  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[032E2030h] 
0000002f  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-10h] 
00000032  call        dword ptr ds:[001E3990h] 
00000038  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h] 
0000003b  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax 
            System.Console.WriteLine("attach now");
0000003e  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[032E2034h] 
00000044  call        5E8D703C 
            System.Console.ReadLine();
00000049  call        5EEAA728 
0000004e  nop 
            e.Release();
0000004f  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
00000052  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
00000054  call        dword ptr ds:[001E3994h] 
0000005a  nop 
            System.Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}", e.Value.Length);
0000005b  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[032E2038h] 
00000061  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax 
00000064  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
00000067  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
00000069  call        dword ptr ds:[001E3998h] 
0000006f  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax 
00000072  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-18h] 
00000075  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx                 ; access violation here
00000077  call        608CBA5B 
0000007c  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax 
0000007f  mov         ecx,5EBE28F8h 
00000084  call        FFF91FB0
00000089  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax 
0000008c  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h] 
0000008f  mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],eax 
00000092  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch] 
00000095  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
00000098  mov         dword ptr [eax+4],edx 
0000009b  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch] 
0000009e  mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],eax 
000000a1  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-20h] 
000000a4  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-24h] 
000000a7  call        5E8CD460 
        }
000000ac  nop 
000000ad  mov         esp,ebp 
000000af  pop         ebp 
000000b0  ret
```

I think I've commented all the relevant lines of code in the incorrect version.  Clearly register `edi` is used to hold a pointer to `e.Value`, which consists <strike>most likely of a pointer to content (at offset 0) and a length (at offset 4)</strike> of the v-table (at offset 0), length (at offset 4), followed immediately by the content.  Unfortunately `e.Value` (the string `"test"`) is copied into `edi` before `e.Value` is cleared, so the length is fetched using the wrong string pointer.  Ouch!

---

Bug filed on Connect (please upvote!): [x86 JIT improperly reorders load of field of generic type with assignment to default(T)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679116/x86-jit-improperly-reorders-load-of-field-of-generic-type-with-assignment-to-default-t)

Comment: @Oskar: it will be.  It's also way too long for a comment.

Comment: indeed too long for a comment, but that does not make it an answer :) Looking forward to a more thorough answer

Comment: (imagines Ben Voigt is comparing IL from the two builds to see if it is the compiler vs JIT, so steps away content it is in capable hands)

Comment: @Marc: I believe the OP who says having the debugger attached makes a difference, so I'm attaching AFTER the JIT runs, to see the native code.

Comment: @Oskar, @Marc, @FatKenny: At this point there's already enough evidence for someone to file a bug on Connect.  I'm a little peeved at the VS2010 debugger, because the Watch window isn't letting me access registers, I wanted to evaluate `EAX = 7` on the line where I commented that it became 4, and see if the output changed.

Comment: @Marc: My bad for not checking the IL between the builds (to divide it being compiler vs. JITer).

Comment: @Ben: Random note: I tend to use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` to get at JITed optimized code (instead of `ReadLine`).

Comment: @FatKenny: If behavior of an optimized build changes depending on whether it's started inside debugger vs attached later, then it's a JIT bug.  You diagnosed that correctly.

Comment: By the way, if you don't want to mess with the ReadLine business, you can edit your debugger settings and un-check the "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" option. That lets you see the same code you would see if you started it outside the debugger.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for filing the bug on Connect.